# How to create new lines with less space HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using `<br>` at the moment to split up my `<p>` tags, problem is though that the `<br>` is creating too much of a space between the text. Is there any way I can have it so there is less of a space?

Comment: Specify a `margin-bottom` for your paragraphs.

Comment: In future I suggest you provide an example of your markup to give us some context. As it stands your question is ambiguous in the placement of the `<br>` tag ie: in the `<p>` tag or used between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `<br />` to create a new line, you can set the `line-height` css style to reduce the text vertical spacing.

If you want to reduce the spacing between tags you can set the `padding` or `margin` (or `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `margin-top`, or `margin-bottom`) on the particular tag you are working with.

Example of `line-height`: http://jsfiddle.net/83sduryy/

Comment: I'm using a css file for this. Would you mind giving an Example?

Comment: #Tag1{
   padding-top;
   margin-right: 700px;

  }

Comment: Added jsfiddle example

Comment: It seems like it is still giving me normal spacing. I want there to be less space between lines.

Comment: You should re-phrase: "you can set the `line-height` css style to reduce the font size". Changing `line-height` will not change the font size, only the amount of space allocated to a line. It possible to have a line-height smaller than the font size of the element.

Comment: Sorry changed, no idea why I wrote that (in a rush)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `<br>` to split up (increase space between?) your `<p>` tags. This is what margins are for in CSS. `<br>` should be used sparingly if at all to break up content in a block element.

CSS

```
 p {margin-bottom:10px; /*Change as needed alos consider 1.25em etc*/}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/do9wdqkn/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a margin to your `<p>` tags. I would advise you add a a class to the paragraphs where you want extra spacing.

Just specify a class e.g. `p-br` for the tags that need extra spacing.

```css
p.p-br {
    margin-bottom: 2em; /* Whatever spacing you want... */
}
```